# foreach with function as array argument

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code:

```php
function get_from_db() {
    $sql = "
    SELECT 
        column_a, 
        column_b, 
        column_c, 
        column_d,
        attribute_name,
        attribute_value,
    FROM 
        my_table mt
        LEFT JOIN columns_attributes ca ON mt.id = cd.fk_column
    ";
  // Execute SQL, returns multiple rows for each attribute
  /*
   $columns_array = [
        [
            'id' => 'xxxxxxx'
            'column_a' => 1,
            'column_b' => 2,
            'column_c' => 3,
            'column_d' => 4,
            'attribute_name' => 'color',
            'attribute_value' => 'red'
        ],
        [
            'id' => 'xxxxxxx'
            'column_a' => 1,
            'column_b' => 2,
            'column_c' => 3,
            'column_d' => 4,
            'attribute_name' => 'weight',
            'attribute_value' => '10KG'
        ],
        [
            'id' => 'yyyyyy'
            'column_a' => 1,
            'column_b' => 2,
            'column_c' => 3,
            'column_d' => 4,
            'attribute_name' => 'color',
            'attribute_value' => 'blue'
        ],
        [
            'id' => 'yyyyyy'
            'column_a' => 1,
            'column_b' => 2,
            'column_c' => 3,
            'column_d' => 4,
            'attribute_name' => 'weight',
            'attribute_value' => '20KG'
        ],
   ]
  */
  return $columns_array;
}
```

Next I want to do some processing so I have an array with a nested array for all attributes because it's easier for me later.

```php
$columns_array = get_from_db();
$tmp = [];
foreach($columns_array as $row) {
    // Do what I need to do so I end up with
    // Something like this
    /*
    $columns_array = [
        'xxxxxxx' => [
            'column_a' => 1,
            'column_b' => 2,
            'column_c' => 3,
            'column_d' => 4,
            'attributes' => [
                'color' => 'red',
                'weight' => '10KG'
            ],
        ],
        'yyyyyy' => [
            'column_a' => 1,
            'column_b' => 2,
            'column_c' => 3,
            'column_d' => 4,
            'attributes' => [
                'color' => 'blue',
                'weight' => '20KG'
            ],
        ],
    ];
    */
}
$columns_array = $tmp;
```

I'm only creating the `$columns_array` to temporarily store the returned array from `get_from_db()`.
Can I use:

```php
foreach(get_from_db() as $row) {
}
```

???

Does the function only execute once?
Is there any quirk I should be aware of if I use a function as the array argument?

PS: I'm not processing the array inside `get_from_db()` because I might need to keep the original return for some different purpose.

Comment: `Does the function only execute once`... a very quick test with some logging / dumping would tell you the answer to this, probably less time than writing this post...

Comment: https://3v4l.org/a7PKK

Comment: Differe if it's a `while` loop though, for example: https://3v4l.org/X9b3n (because it's not looping the result of the function)

Comment: or some research using Google surely would help. Asking other people to google for you won't get you much far in the trade of programming